# Using libcurl to send a POST request that mimics a browser

Tags: c++, post, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to send **POST** request to a specific website:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, web.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

And the website won't show me the result of the **POST** request, I think it is because the curl request didn't act like a "real browser".
Is there a better way to make a curl request that mimics a browser the best?
Or do you think the problem is different.

Comment: I suggest you get hold of a copy of etherial and look at the traffic that really goes between your browser and the site. I suspect there are several cookies involved. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark

Comment: 1. "ethereal" is called Wireshark these days. 2. Also consider the "copy as curl" command that both browsers (that matter) feature, and convert that to libcurl code with --libcurl...

Comment: Also, I think that you need to set the `CURLOPT_POST` option: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1)`. [CURLOPT_POST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POST.html) shows that it's disabled by default, of course.

Comment: @Dillan I tried this yesterday and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg Can you give me some guidance? I do not know much about this feature.

Comment: i've not heard of "copy as curl". which browsers support it?

Comment: [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Copy_as_cURL) and [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#copying-requests-as-curl-commands) for instance.

Comment: I have built a simple login form, the libcurl is sending the post request successfully if there are no "action" filed involved. (If so, I get the source of the page I have been in, and the libcurl doesn't follow).
Other websites in the libcurl doesn't even send the post request and I get the login form again and again. What is the problem? @DanielStenberg